# If keeping the S-Boxes secret in SPN ciphers increase they security, does using one different S-Box set per round in them increases even more?

Tags: aes, block-cipher, s-boxes, white-box

I read in [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/144.pdf) that keeping the S-boxes secret in AES raise its security from 128-256-bits to 1812-1940-bits.

Let's suppose I use one different S-Boxes set per single round.

/\ Does this increases security even more than using only the same S-boxes set in entire cipher?

Comment: You can't just randomize the S-box and call it a day. A random S-box may actually be _less_ secure than one that's chosen with specific security properties, which is the case of the AES S-box. Note that some ciphers actually do use a different S-box on each round, [like Serpent](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67986/54184), but this is done because the S-boxes are very small (only 4 bits), so it's easy to exhaustively iterate through all $2^4!$ possible tables to find ideal properties.

Comment: @forest I already read that book, what I asked is if using different S-boxes sets per per each round could possible increase the security of the encipherment,

Comment: I think there are other answers here which discuss AES with changing S-boxes.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confused. The abstract states the *opposite*:

> **Abstract:**

> How does the security of the AES change when the S-box is
> replaced by a secret S-box, about which the adversary has no knowledge?
> Would it be safe to reduce the number of encryption rounds?
> In this paper, we demonstrate attacks based on integral cryptanalysis which allow to recover both the secret key and the secret S-box for respectively four, five, and six rounds of the AES.

> Despite the significantly larger amount of secret information which an adversary needs
> to recover, the attacks are very efficient with time/data complexities of
> $2^{17}/2^{16},2^{38}/2^{40}$ and $2^{90}/2^{64},$ respectively.

> Another interesting aspect of our attack is that it works both as chosen
> plaintext and as chosen ciphertext attack. Surprisingly, the chosen ciphertext variant has a significantly lower time complexity in the attacks on four and five round, compared to the respective chosen plaintext attacks.

In conclusion *even though the nominal keylength is much longer* the attacks demonstrated do not exhibit a corresponding increase in computational complexity.

**Remark:** An attack complexity of $2^f$ is equivalent to $f$ bits of security, typically measured by $2^f$ encryptions/decryptions in terms of time and $2^f$ blocks of memory in terms of space.